# cakephp component $this->controller->modelClass

Tags: cakephp, model, components, cakephp-1.3

In Component I try to access Myprofile Model

```
class SignMeupComponent extends Object
   public function register() {
    $this->__isLoggedIn();
    if (!empty($this->controller->data)) {
        extract($this->settings);
        $model = $this->controller->modelClass;
        $this->controller->loadModel($model);
         $this->controller->{$model}->Myprofile->save($this->controller->data);
       $this->controller->data['Myprofile']['user_id'] = $this->controller->{$model}->id;
        $this->controller->{$model}->set($this->controller->data);
            if ($this->controller->{$model}->validates()) {
```

1. how to use $this->controller->modelclass
2. how to use any model in component

thank for any suggest

Comment: ok thank john I'm newbie 
now I understand rule

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`$this->controller` is not defined by default. You have to save a reference to the controller manually, for example in the `initialize()` method of your component:

```
public function initialize(&$controller, $settings = array()) {
    $this->controller = $controller;
}
```

Then you should be able to access the controller's properties and methods.

Comment: thank I 'm sorry I've already announced initialize()
but To be part of the function only 
I should be coming down all the code or not.
I just want to know that I want to access what the other models 
When it is in component