# How to access params in components in cake php?

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-2.1, cakephp-1.2

Access `$this->params` and `$this->data` in components.

```
class LoginComponent extends Object {
   /*  */
   public function login() {   
      pr($this->params);
      pr($this->data);
   }
}
```

I am using this in cake **v1.2**. I would like to know solution of this in **v1.2** as well as **v2.1**. Please give me a suggestion.

Comment: you need to pass reference to controller..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Have a look at some components in your lib. I know this for Cake 2.x, not for 1.2.x. *update: as [mark](https://stackoverflow.com/users/461173/mark) mentioned in the [comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14559499/how-to-access-params-in-components-in-cake-php/14559887#comment20313752_14559887), this works the same for the 1.x versions.*

For example, when I open the `SecurityComponent` I will find a function called `startup()`. This method defines itself as:

```
public function startup(Controller $controller) {
     //Rest of code goes here
}
```

as you can see, they `import` the Controller object. What you could right now is access the Controlelr methods and variables. Because as you might know: the `$this` when calling `$this->data` refers to the `Controller`.

So, if I store this `$controller` in a protected variable called `$_Controller` in my component, I can easily access the data and params like so:

```
# CakePhp 2.x
$this->_Controller->request->data;
$this->_Controller->request->params;

# CakePhp 1.x
$this->_Controller->data;
$this->_Controller->params;
```

Have a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5983633/cakephp-component-this-controller-modelclass) as well.

Comment: it is not any different in 1.x. the controller is passed in those versions, as well.

Comment: What is difference between `startup` and `initialize` functions?

Comment: also, for 2.x you usually access the response class. for write access you even need to. And I would not use private, but protected here.

Comment: @Justin the order in which it is executed - see http://www.dereuromark.de/2013/01/22/cakephp-tips/

Comment: @mark Why use the response class? Because every component built by the Cake Dev team, I see them `importing` the Controller object. Can you refer to an article or something where they explain why I should use the `response` class instead? I changed my answer to a protected variable :)

Comment: @mark Hmm, in the PaginatorComponent they are importing the complete `ComponentCollection` and use `$this->Controller = $collection->getController();` instead. An article would be nice. I would like to know which is best :) (or recommended)

Comment: sry, i meant the "request" object! `$this->_Controller->request->params['named']['x'] = 'y';` (only with request object you are allowed to modify the params in 2.x)

Comment: @mark Ah yes that's true. I was answering for 2.x but used the 1.x convention used by Justin. A bit confusing :) I will change it (again) haha. This also applies for the data.

Comment: you might want to devide your answer into 1.x and 2.x - since for 1.x you need to not (= cannot) use the request object :)

Comment: The request and response classes are added in 2.x, is it?

Comment: @mark Done. Do you agree with this answer boss? Now upvote it! haha.

Comment: @JustinJohn I believe it is, yes. But I am sure Mark will know this :)

Answer (score 0):

Check by Router:
`Router::getParams();`